# How to exclude a group of items from a report in SQL for Lansweeper

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that runs a report for unauthorized software. There is some computers that I want to exclude from the report, I created a group containing the computers that need to be exempt. I can not get the where not command to work in conjunction with the other variables. I am green to SQL so this might be simple but I can not figure out what is wrong with my syntax.

The group name that I want excluded is 'Test'. Without the not command it will show only the computers in the group. So the group works I just need it to do the inverse and only show what is not in the group.

```
Select Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetID,
  tblAssets.AssetUnique,
  tblAssets.Description,
  tblSoftwareUni.softwareName As Software,
  tblSoftware.softwareVersion As Version,
  tblSoftware.Lastchanged,
  tsysOS.Image As icon,
  tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup
From tblSoftware
  Inner Join tblAssets On tblSoftware.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
  Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftware.softID = tblSoftwareUni.SoftID
  Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
  Inner Join tsysOS On tblAssets.OScode = tsysOS.OScode
  Inner Join tblAssetGroupLink On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetGroupLink.AssetID
  Inner Join tblAssetGroups On tblAssetGroups.AssetGroupID =
    tblAssetGroupLink.AssetGroupID
Where Not tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup = 'Noah Test' And tblSoftwareUni.Approved =
  2 And tblAssetCustom.State = 1
Order By tblAssets.AssetName,
  Software
```

Comment: Please tag what DBMS you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, mySQL), etc.

Comment: Where tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup != 'Noah Test' or try <> to compare not equal to

Answer (score 0):

For this operation, you can use the `LIKE` keyword. Except, as you indicated, we need `NOT`

So,

```
Select Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetID,
  tblAssets.AssetUnique,
  tblAssets.Description,
  tblSoftwareUni.softwareName As Software,
  tblSoftware.softwareVersion As Version,
  tblSoftware.Lastchanged,
  tsysOS.Image As icon,
  tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup
From tblSoftware
  Inner Join tblAssets On tblSoftware.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
  Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftware.softID = tblSoftwareUni.SoftID
  Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
  Inner Join tsysOS On tblAssets.OScode = tsysOS.OScode
  Inner Join tblAssetGroupLink On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetGroupLink.AssetID
  Inner Join tblAssetGroups On tblAssetGroups.AssetGroupID =
    tblAssetGroupLink.AssetGroupID
Where tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup NOT LIKE '%Noah Test%' And tblSoftwareUni.Approved =
  2 And tblAssetCustom.State = 1
Order By tblAssets.AssetName,
  Software
```

If the text is always going to just be `Noah Test`, you could use `NOT EQUALS`, which is evaluated with `!=` or `<>`

```
Select Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetID,
  tblAssets.AssetUnique,
  tblAssets.Description,
  tblSoftwareUni.softwareName As Software,
  tblSoftware.softwareVersion As Version,
  tblSoftware.Lastchanged,
  tsysOS.Image As icon,
  tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup
From tblSoftware
  Inner Join tblAssets On tblSoftware.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
  Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftware.softID = tblSoftwareUni.SoftID
  Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
  Inner Join tsysOS On tblAssets.OScode = tsysOS.OScode
  Inner Join tblAssetGroupLink On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetGroupLink.AssetID
  Inner Join tblAssetGroups On tblAssetGroups.AssetGroupID =
    tblAssetGroupLink.AssetGroupID
Where tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup != 'Noah Test' And tblSoftwareUni.Approved =
  2 And tblAssetCustom.State = 1
Order By tblAssets.AssetName,
  Software
```